# How to set globally-accessible context variables in django template tags?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-debug-toolbar

There is a template tag which returns a random element from the list. I also need to save all the elements that were in the list and the one that had been picked in context, and later depict that information in django-debug-toolbar panel.

```py
from django import template
import random

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True, name='pickrandomelementtag')
def pickrandomelementtag(context, list_of_random_elements):
    context.dicts[0]["key18"] = "value19"
    return random.choice(list_of_random_elements)
```

So I test setting the variables functionality with given line:

```py
context.dicts[0]["key18"] = "value19"
```

I am able to access the {{key18}} within the template, but my aim is set this variable in a manner that it would be accessible later on (globally?) from django-debug-toolbar panel. That's where i'm stuck.

Here is my django-debug-toolbar panels.py file:

```py
from debug_toolbar.panels import Panel
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.template.response import SimpleTemplateResponse



class RandomPanel(Panel):
    name = "RandomPanel;"
    has_content = True
    template = 'panels/randompanel.html'

    def title(self):
        return _('Random Panel')

    def generate_stats(self, request, response):
        print('that is where I need to access key18')
        self.record_stats(
            {
                "request": request
            }
        )
```

How would I access context variable `key18` in `generate_stats` method of RandomPanel class object? Or maybe `context` is a wrong place to set custom cariables within template tags and you'd advise other approaches? Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to get these values in the debug toolbar?

Comment: You could use a custom context manager to add the random value to the context and also set it on the request so that you would have access to it in your panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually store the information in the request itself. Assuming that the `context_processor` has `django.template.context_processors.request` (which is there in default settings)

```py
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True, name='pickrandomelementtag')
def pickrandomelementtag(context, list_of_random_elements):
    context['request'].META['MY_INFO'] = "value19"
    return random.choice(list_of_random_elements)
```

Then you have the `request` object in the `Panel` where you can use this information.