# Access a variable from template tag that takes arguments

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters, templatetags

I have a template tags that takes ID on template and returns a list, I want to check the list if the variable is available and make checkbox input checked.

```
`_checkbox.html`
{% load get_previous_response %}

{% user_response question.id %} {# this returns a list of ids #}

So I want to do something like this

<input type="checkbox" {% if option.id in user_response %}checked{% endif %}>
problem is the above won't work, I tried django templatetag `with template context`

My main goal is I want to access the list returned by {% user_response question.id %}.
```

**EDIT**

My custom templatetag.

`get_previous_response.py`

```
from django import template
from survey.models import Question
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def user_response(context, question_id):
    question = Question.objects.filter(id=question_id).first()
    user = context['request'].user
    response = question.get_simple_answer(user)
    return response
```

Comment: Please share more code (`urls.py`, `models.py`, `views.py`)

Comment: I think the code and explanation is sufficient enough for the problem I currently have.

Comment: Not sure if we need views or models code, but do you mind sharing your templatetags implementation?

Comment: I have added the template tag.

Comment: I have had this kind of problem before, getting a variable out of a template tag function that accepts an argument.

Comment: @NixonSparrow, it's a custom template tag! and it's there in the question! I guess everyone that answered could read mind as well.

Comment: @NixonSparrow, I think Cynthia's example follows the minimal, reproducible guideline(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and there's no reason to downvote her based on sentiments.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I've changed the vote to up. I wanted to do too many question at the same time.

Comment: That's understandable, thanks for reviewing that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways to achieve this.

1. From the [django docs on simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag):

> It’s possible to store the tag results in a template variable rather than directly outputting it. This is done by using the as argument followed by the variable name. Doing so enables you to output the content yourself where you see fit

In your case, that would be something like this:

`{% user_response question.id  as user_responses %}`

2. Another approach would be to add the list in the request context, and access it from there. The downside is that this will be available in all your templates(which I guess is not what you want).
   See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57259205/3865670) on how to do that.
3. Implement a Templatetag class and set the context in the render method. Here is the Django doc for how to do that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
{% if option.id in user_response %}
   <input type="checkbox" checked>
{% else %}
   <input type="checkbox">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It's more elegant way, but for that issue it does not matter.